# Why comparing these javascript objects wont return True?

Tags: javascript, operators

The == operator is supposed to compare the same data types and return True. But, the expressions before return false.

```
console.log(new String("A") == new String("A"));
console.log([1, 2, 3] == [1, 2, 3]);
```

Comment: Because `new String(...)` creates a String object, and two objects are never `==` or `===` to each other per ECMA-262.

Comment: any instance is different (does not share the same object reference).